# Tracking outbound links from the site

Tags: hyperlink, outbound

Hi I have a site which has a number of affiliate links, I would like to measure which ones perform best. I could be using the same link say in the sidebar and at the end of each article, and I want to know which is best, the sidebar one, or the one after the article.

How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each of the links, try adding an `onclick` JS snippet with Google Analytics event tracking, or a similar self-created code or code from another analytics suite you use. I do something similar, creating a fake pageview for my download links by adding this in the `onclick`

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/<?=$idnumber?>/download']);
```